# Rails - Handling Deep Model Hierarchies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

I have a user model with three additional models that its associated with: **City**, **State**, **Country**. Their associations are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city
  has_one :state
  has_one :country
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :user
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I'd like to do is create a form that allows new/existing users to add such information to their profile. But after trying this out in the rails console I'm finding that to accomplish this things become heavily chained.

```
city       = City.create(name: "New York City")
city.state = state 

state         = State.create(name: "New York")
state.country = country

country = Country.create(name: "United States")

user         = User.create(name: "John Doe")
user.city    = City.first
user.state   = user.city.state
user.country = user.state.country
```

My end goal is to be able to create select boxes or inputs with autcomplete that would be able to retrieve and return data for what's selected. So if I choose New York City in the select box for City, then the State select box would return New York (parent-child pairing). Is there a better way to assign these models to one another?

**Bonus Point**: For showing the controller logic. As I continue to think things over there would most likely come a time where a user enters a new state, city, or country that wasn't available on the site. I'm assuming my create/update for my user controller would look something like this but as far as the other remaining actions I can't seem to think of a solution?

```
# users_controller.rb
def create
  @user.build_city
  @user.build_state
  @user.build_country
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Carl, I recommend you to Load your location tables completely only once. This way, a creation of city, state or country will almost never occur.

If I'm not mistaken, this site provide APIs or you can download the complete database to load into yours. Take a look: http://www.geonames.org

See an example:
http://blog.inspired.no/populate-your-database-with-free-world-cities-countries-regions-in-2-minutes-using-a-rails-migration-273/

There is also this guy who created a gem to initialize cities, states and countries. But I have not tested: https://github.com/mettadore/geoinfo

Comment: With GeoNames, would I still keep keep my associations as they are in the question? Also Would you have any idea on how I would configure my views/controller as far as assigning these values?

Comment: By the way I just wanted to say I really like the idea of pre-populating the db, the question now is setting up my user model with these attributes.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example of creating the table and using migration to import the data.

Comment: From the examples provided I decided to do a little bit more research and was able to find and use the Geocoder gem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for accomplishing what I was aiming to do. I'll create an answer which details the steps.

Comment: Great Carl. Good luck in your project.

Comment: Thanks! I greatly appreciate your help in leading me to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants to accomplish creating models that have geographic attributes I found and decided to use the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder). Once installed this is what my User model ended up looking like. Just note that the attributes should the three attributes would obviously need to be added to your model for this to work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_validation :geocode

  geocoded_by :address do |obj,results|
    if geo = results.first
      obj.state = geo.state
      obj.country = geo.country
      obj.city = geo.city
      obj.province = geo.province
    end
  end
end
```